# List filter error after migration from SharePoint 2007 to 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, list-view, migration, filter

I have this problem after the migration from SharePoint 2007 to 2010 :

When i try to filter a list from any site there's an Internet Explorer Javascript Error "_layouts/filter.aspx" permission denied appear.

Any help would be most welcome !

Comment: similar question found  http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Server/MS-SharePoint/Q_24118078.html maybe somone can get the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On alternate access mappings we have to add entry on "Intranet" zone not on "Default zone",

this the solution :)